# Cognos calculation and aggregation

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I want to do the following.

I have warranty Claim Dates - each Claim is a single instance with Dates attached. Now I want to see the time elapsed from failure date to repair date.

However this Report is huge. So I want to see the median of the elapsed time for each dealer.

I know it would be possible with SQL but is that also possible in Cognos?

BR
Richard

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions: You have data items called [Failure Date], [Repair Date], and [Dealer]. You want to measure the time in days.

Create a new data item with the following expresion:

```
average(_days_between([Repair Date],[Failure Date]) for [Dealer])
```

Set the Aggregate Function property for the new data item to 'Calculated'.

Comment: Thanks - that helped!

Comment: the same thing will work using 'median' instead of 'average'.